# Logger entries translated to the UI stops being updated with time

Tags: logging, javafx, javafx-2

I have a javafx.concurrent.Task that run some code in background and use the java.util.logging.Logger to give information about its status. I need to show this log entry in the UI in the main thread. how can I do this?

this is a simple toy project I've made to solve the problem out of the context

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


    ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
    final ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
    list.setItems(items);

    Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            doStuff();
            return "yey";
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).start();



    Scene scene = new Scene(list, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void doStuff() {
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI").log(Level.INFO, "error");
        }
        Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI").log(Level.SEVERE, "whatever");
    }

[...]
}
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
public class LoggerUI extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println("UI"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());


    ListView<String> list = new ListView<>();
    final ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
    list.setItems(items);

    Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI").addHandler(new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void publish(LogRecord lr) {
            System.out.println("publish()"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());

            items.add(lr.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() {
            System.out.println("flush");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws SecurityException {
            System.out.println("close");

        }
    });

    Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            doStuff();
            return "yey";
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).start();



    Scene scene = new Scene(list, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void doStuff() {

    System.out.println("doStuff()"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
    for (int i=0;i<300;i++) {
        final int j =i;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI").log(Level.INFO, "error");
        }

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("runLater()"+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI").log(Level.SEVERE, "whatever" +j);
                }
            });
    }

   [..]

}
}
```

it shows the first 20-30th entries and then stop to update the UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It's not actually JavaFX issue, but java logging's one.

Store Logger into variable, because Loggers returned by `Logger.getLogger()` are not the same each time, they are cached, garbage collected and stuff.

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("LoggerUI");
```

and use as follows:

```
logger.addHandler(new Handler() { ... });

logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "whatever" +j);
```

Also, I would advise to move `Platform.runLater()` call to `publish()` methods, so your logger will work from any thread.

Comment: in the second example I'm actually using Platform.runLater()

Comment: method `publish()` is called from `doStuff()` which is called from `new Thread().start()` which is not FX thread.

Comment: at line 65 of the second example I use Platform.runLater() and then inside I call the logger. if you are referring to line 62 where I log "error" than it doesn't really matter because that line is never reached and this is a toy example. thanks for helping anyway

Comment: I see now, I was wrong about root cause of your problem. See updated answer

Comment: thank you very much! I think you're totally right, I'll try tonight when I'll get home and I'll accept the answer :)