# Cannot reset StringBuffer in JavaFX Application

Tags: java, javafx, stringbuffer

I am working on a college course project, a JavaFX application that is simulating a garage with vehicles moving around. Following on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774943/3476528), I created a mechanism for constantnly refreshing GUI without flooding the JavaFX thread.

The entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/ngrahovac/Garage/commit/bcb528e2fea5cd8d6dc2a616d9463d7ffd924a91).

`Observer` is a daemon thread whose task is computing a `String` value for output and sending it it to a `TextArea`, which is constantly being updated.

**Observer run method:**

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (Garage.getLock()) {
                try {
//                  buffer = new StringBuffer("");

                    buffer.append('\n');
                    garage.print(buffer);
                    buffer.append('\n');
                    garage.outputText.set(buffer.toString());
                    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
                    Garage.getLock().wait(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Garage.getLock().notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`Observer` object has a reference to the model class - `garage`. `print()` method of the `Garage` class basically appends stuff to the buffer.

The complete output is printed to the console, which works fine. The output is also used to set `outputText`, a `SimpleStringProperty`, which has a listener attached in the `MainControllerClass`.

**outputText member:**

```
public class Garage implements Externalizable {
    ...
    public SimpleStringProperty outputText = new SimpleStringProperty();
    ...
}
```

Refreshing the GUI is initiated with a button click.

**MainController class:**

```
package garage.controller;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import garage.model.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea output;

    @FXML
    private Button startButton;

    private Garage model;

    public MainController() {

    }

    private AtomicInteger control = new AtomicInteger(-1);

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleStartButton() {
        model.outputText.addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, final String oldValue,
                    final String newValue) {
                if (control.getAndSet(1) == -1) {
                    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            control.set(-1);
                            output.setText(newValue);
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void setModel(Garage model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

When I run the application and click the button, everything is going well. `TextArea` is updated in real time. Since the output is constantly being appended to the `StringBuffer`, I wanted to refresh it in every cycle and get something like a simulation.

This is where the problems start.

When I uncomment the line in the `Observer run` method

```
//                  buffer = new StringBuffer("");
```

nothing is being printed to the `TextArea`. The console output is working well.

I also tried with other `StringBuffer` methods like `delete` and `setLenght` but nothing seems to work. However I try to clean the buffer, `TextArea` is no longer updated.

**I cannot seem to reset the** `StringBuffer`.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT: `print()` methods**

**Garage print method**

```
public void print(StringBuffer buffer) {
        synchronized (Garage.lock) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (int i = 0; i < platformCount; i++)
                    platforms.get(i).print(buffer);
            }
        }
    }
```

**GarageItem print method**

```
package garage.model;

import java.io.*;

public interface GarageItem extends Serializable {
    public void print(StringBuffer buffer);

}
```

**Lane print method**

```
package garage.model;

public class Lane implements GarageItem {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5L;

    @Override
    public void print(StringBuffer buffer) {
        synchronized (Garage.getLock()) {
            buffer.append('.');
        }
    }
}
```

**ParkingSpot print method**

```
package garage.model;

public class ParkingSpot implements GarageItem {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;

    @Override
    public void print(StringBuffer buffer) {
        synchronized (Garage.getLock()) {
            buffer.append('*');
        }

    }

}
```

**Vehicle print method**

```
@Override
    public void print(StringBuffer buffer) {
        synchronized (Garage.getLock()) {
            buffer.append(symbol);
        }
    }
```

where `symbol` is 'V'.

Comment: What does `garage.print` look like? How does it append stuff to the buffer? Does this "stuff" change between iterations?

Comment: @fabian appends more stuff onto the buffer. Since `Garage` has a list of `Platform`s which are matrices of `GarageItem`s, it goes over every platform and appends the char symbol of every item to the buffer. 

The same string is being printed to the console and is working fine. `TextArea` is also being updated. But when I try to reset the buffer in every iteration, `TextArea` is no longer updated as it should be. I will edit the question and add these methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer today. My text example was trivial and by the time I clicked the `handleStartButton`, all of the cars have finished moving and parked in the garage.

Because I reset the buffer in every loop iteration, it meant that the state of the garage didn't change anymore and it's `String` representation was the same. Because of this, change listener was not triggered and nothing was printed out to the TextArea.